# Consumo máximo de memoria no bash do linux usando o openssl com o aes

Tags: linux, memória, bash, openssl, aes

```
#!/bin/sh
SUM = 0
for i in {1..5}
do
t=$((/ usr / bin / time-f '% e' openssl enc -aes-128-ecb -K 1234567890 -in t -out g 1> /dev/null) 2> &1)
SUM = `bc <<<" $ SUM + $ t "`
done
res = bc <<< "scale = 4; $ SUM / 5"
echo $res
```

O código acima, mostra o tempo médio das 5 repetições do openssl usando a cifra AES. Pegando a mesma ideia, como posso obter o máximo consumo de memória?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Talvez consiga fazer o que pretende utilizando o comando [`time(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html). Segundo a [página do *man*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html) do comando ele suporta *format strings* com funcionalidades específicas para reportar utilização de memória:

> **Memory**
>
> **%M**     Maximum resident set size of the process during its lifetime,
>                 in Kbytes.
>
> **%t**     (Not in tcsh(1).)  Average resident set size of the process,
>                 in Kbytes.
>
> **%K**     Average total (data+stack+text) memory use of the process, in
>                 Kbytes.

Qualquer das formas recomendo a dar uma vista de olhos à pergunta [Comando Unix para dizer quanta RAM foi usada durante o tempo de execução do programa?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375889/unix-command-to-tell-how-much-ram-was-used-during-program-runtime/375910) *(em Inglês)* dos nossos amigos do [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) pois fazem um bom trabalho em explicar como funciona a memória em Linux e explica o porquê de ser muito difícil (*ou até impossível*) medir com precisão o que pretende.